# snakeyaml and spark results in an inability to construct objects

Tags: scala, apache-spark, snakeyaml

The following code executes fine in a scala shell given snakeyaml version 1.17

```
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
import scala.beans.BeanProperty

class EmailAccount {
  @scala.beans.BeanProperty var accountName: String = null

  override def toString: String = {
    return s"acct ($accountName)"
  }
}

val text = """accountName: Ymail Account"""

val yaml = new Yaml(new Constructor(classOf[EmailAccount]))
val e = yaml.load(text).asInstanceOf[EmailAccount]
println(e)
```

However when running in spark (2.0.0 in this case) the resulting error is:

```
org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.ConstructorException: Can't construct a java object for tag:yaml.org,2002:EmailAccount; exception=java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: EmailAccount.<init>()
 in 'string', line 1, column 1:
    accountName: Ymail Account
    ^

  at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructYamlObject.construct(Constructor.java:350)
  at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructObject(BaseConstructor.java:182)
  at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructDocument(BaseConstructor.java:141)
  at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.getSingleData(BaseConstructor.java:127)
  at org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.loadFromReader(Yaml.java:450)
  at org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.load(Yaml.java:369)
  ... 48 elided
Caused by: org.yaml.snakeyaml.error.YAMLException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: EmailAccount.<init>()
  at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructMapping.createEmptyJavaBean(Constructor.java:220)
  at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructMapping.construct(Constructor.java:190)
  at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructYamlObject.construct(Constructor.java:346)
  ... 53 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: EmailAccount.<init>()
  at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2810)
  at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2053)
  at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructMapping.createEmptyJavaBean(Constructor.java:216)
  ... 55 more
```

I launched the scala shell with

```
scala -classpath "/home/placey/snakeyaml-1.17.jar"
```

I launched the spark shell with

```
/home/placey/Downloads/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-shell --master local --jars /home/placey/snakeyaml-1.17.jar
```

Comment: it says it can not find Student class, is it a yaml class or your custom class in your application ? Do you import it from another jar ?

Comment: That is a custom class in the application. Instantiating it directly works fine.

Comment: @placeybordeaux Did my answer solve your problem?

Comment: @PawełBartkiewicz I haven't tested it yet, I will assign bounty & accept as soon as I do.

Comment: @placeybordeaux Thanks, I just wanted to know if there's something I could improve in my answer. Sorry if it felt like nagging, it's definitely a good idea to wait until the end of bounty period. It's always possible someone would come up with a better answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Solution

Create a [self-contained application](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html#self-contained-applications) and run it using `spark-submit` instead of using `spark-shell`.

I've created a minimal project for you as a [gist here](https://gist.github.com/tues/22b1b4644fd40195bababb3e94e4aaa5). All you need to do is put both files (`build.sbt` and `Main.scala`) in some directory, then run:

```bash
sbt package
```

in order to create a JAR. The JAR will be in `target/scala-2.11/sparksnakeyamltest_2.11-1.0.jar` or a similar location. You can [get SBT from here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/) if you haven't used it yet. Finally, you can run the project:

```bash
/home/placey/Downloads/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-submit --class "Main" --master local --jars /home/placey/snakeyaml-1.17.jar target/scala-2.11/sparksnakeyamltest_2.11-1.0.jar
```

The output should be:

```
[many lines of Spark's log)]
acct (Ymail Account)
[more lines of Spark's log)]
```

## Explanation

Spark's shell ([REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop)) transforms all classes you define in it by adding `$iw` parameter to your constructors. I've [explained it here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40689204/4642274). SnakeYAML expects a zero-parameter constructor for JavaBean-like classes, but there isn't one, so it fails.

You can try this yourself:

```scala
scala> class Foo() {}
defined class Foo

scala> classOf[Foo].getConstructors()
res0: Array[java.lang.reflect.Constructor[_]] = Array(public Foo($iw))

scala> classOf[Foo].getConstructors()(0).getParameterCount
res1: Int = 1
```

As you can see, Spark transforms the constructor by adding a parameter of type `$iw`.

## Alternative solutions

### Define your own `Constructor`

If you really need to get it working in the shell, you could define your own class implementing `org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor` and make sure that `$iw` gets passed to constructors, but this is a lot of work (I actually wrote my own `Constructor` in Scala for security reasons some time ago, so I have some experience with this).

You could also define a custom `Constructor` hard-coded to instantiate a specific class (`EmailAccount` in your case) similar to the `DiceConstructor` [shown in SnakeYAML's documentation](https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml/wiki/Documentation#markdown-header-constructors-representers-resolvers). This is much easier, but requires writing code for each class you want to support.

Example:

```scala
case class EmailAccount(accountName: String)

class EmailAccountConstructor extends org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor {

  val emailAccountTag = new org.yaml.snakeyaml.nodes.Tag("!emailAccount")
  this.rootTag = emailAccountTag
  this.yamlConstructors.put(emailAccountTag, new ConstructEmailAccount)

  private class ConstructEmailAccount extends org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.AbstractConstruct {
    def construct(node: org.yaml.snakeyaml.nodes.Node): Object = {
      // TODO: This is fine for quick prototyping in a REPL, but in a real
      //       application you should probably add type checks.
      val mnode = node.asInstanceOf[org.yaml.snakeyaml.nodes.MappingNode]
      val mapping = constructMapping(mnode)
      val name = mapping.get("accountName").asInstanceOf[String]
      new EmailAccount(name)
    }
  }

}
```

You can save this as a file and load it in the REPL using `:load filename.scala`.

Bonus advantage of this solution is that it can create immutable case class instances directly. Unfortunately Scala REPL seems to have issues with imports, so I've used fully qualified names.

### Don't use JavaBeans

You can also just parse YAML documents as simple Java maps:

```scala
scala> val yaml2 = new Yaml()
yaml2: org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml = Yaml:1141996301

scala> val e2 = yaml2.load(text)
e2: Object = {accountName=Ymail Account}

scala> val map = e2.asInstanceOf[java.util.Map[String, Any]]
map: java.util.Map[String,Any] = {accountName=Ymail Account}

scala> map.get("accountName")
res4: Any = Ymail Account
```

This way SnakeYAML won't need to use reflection.

However, since you're using Scala, I recommend trying
[MoultingYAML](https://github.com/jcazevedo/moultingyaml), which is a Scala wrapper for SnakeYAML. It parses YAML documents to simple Java types and then maps them to Scala types (even your own types like `EmailAccount`).

Comment: is this the same problem fixed in snakeyaml 1.17? https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml/issues/318/constructorgetclassforname-cant-find-class